# Logging in nodejs using bunyan logger, Print DEBUG, INFO, ERROR to same file

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, hapi.js, bunyan

I have defined the logger.js as below:

```
var bunyan = require('bunyan');

var bunyanOpts = {
    name: 'my-api',
    streams: [
        {
            level: 'info',
            path: 'logs/mylogs.log'  
        }
    ]
};
```

Using this I am only able to print info level logs , is there a way I can print Debug, trace, warn, error in the same file?

Comment: Change the level from `info` to `trace`?

Comment: perfect , this works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `level` property of a stream configuration sets the minimum level for that particular log stream. In your case, only messages with a level of `info` or higher will be logged to the logfile.

If you want it to log messages with lower levels (`trace` being the lowest), you can change the minimum level in the configuration:

```
var bunyanOpts = {
  name    : 'my-api',
  streams : [{
    level   : 'trace',
    path    : 'logs/mylogs.log'
  }]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple streams writing to the same file I think

```
var bunyanOpts = {
   name: 'my-api',
   streams: [
      {
        level: 'info',
        path: 'logs/mylogs.log'  
      },
      {
        level: 'debug',
        path: 'logs/mylogs.log'  
      },
  ]
```

};